# How to replace text in text file using .SH file script?

Tags: regex, linux, scripting, replace

So I want to create a script that takes 3 arguments - path to file, exact word to replace and with what to replace it. How to create such thing?

Generally I want6 it to have api like `sudo script.sh "C:/myTextDoc.xml" "_WORD_TO_REPLACE_" "WordTo Use"`

Answer (score 4):

You don't need a script, a simple sed would do (if you're running under cygwin or a POSIX-compliant OS):

```
sed -i '' 's/_WORD_TO_REPLACE_/WordTo Use/' "C:/myTextDoc.xml"
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
#!/bin/bash
sed -e "s/$2/$3/g" <$1 >$1.$$ && cp $1.$$ $1 && rm $1.$$
```

Alternatively, you can use the single command

```
sed -i -e "s/$2/$3/g" $1
```

as Yan suggested. I generally use the first form myself. I have seen systems where `-i` is not supported (SunOS).

This will replace all instances of the second argument with the third, in the file passed as the first. For example, `./replace file oldword newword`

Comment: sed has the ability to edit files in place without the need to make temp files by hand.

Comment: Instead of 3 commands and a temp file `sed -i "s/$2/$3/g" $1` will work just fine.

Comment: @yan Neat, I didn't know that :-)

Comment: @Johnathan: edit and save only by combining both sed options, like : sed -i -e "s/foo/bar/g" my_file

Answer (score 0):

Ruby(1.9+)

```
$ ruby -i.bak -ne 'print $_.gsub(/WORD_TO_REPLACE/,"New Word")' /path/to/file
```